# What is the best practice to replace class name using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor tag, or a btn. I'm trying to add the proper style when it is disable using jQuery.

```
<a id="course-progress-report-btn" href="#" class="disabled">
    <div class="sprites report_icon_blue"></div>
    <span>COURSE PROGRESS REPORT</span>
</a>
```

I want to select the div, and replace the class `report_icon_blue` to class `report_icon_gray`.

How do I do that using jQuery ?

I've tried

```
//course progress report
if(showReport){
    courseProgressBtn.attr('href', window.rel_path+'teacher/reports/course-summary?courseId='+id+'&classroomId='+selectedClassroom).removeClass('disabled');
}else{
    courseProgressBtn.attr('href', '#').addClass('disabled').next('.sprites').removeClass('report_icon_blue').addClass('report_icon_grey');
}
```

I couldn't get it to swap the image.

Result

[image]

Comment: It would be cleaner to define a CSS rule `a.disabled .sprites.report_icon`

Comment: so, you're not looking for a best practice, you're looking for a solution.

Comment: Look at: http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh This requires the jQuery UI framework and is primarily for animating between classes. I wouldn't recommend this as best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use toggleClass with a boolean..

```
// Passing true will make sure the class exists

// Passing false will make sure the class **doesn't exist**

$("#course-progress-report-btn div").toggleClass("report_icon_blue", true);
$("#course-progress-report-btn div").toggleClass("report_icon_gray", false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't working because you need to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of `.next()`.

```
courseProgressBtn.attr('href', '#')
                 .addClass('disabled')
                 .find('.sprites')
                 .removeClass('report_icon_blue')
                 .addClass('report_icon_grey');
```

Personally I would make this clearer by refactoring to:

```
courseProgressBtn.attr('href', '#')
                 .addClass('disabled')

var $icon = courseProgressBtn.find(".sprites");
$icon.removeClass('report_icon_blue')
     .addClass('report_icon_grey');
```

---

Alternatively as [@Denys Séguret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252818/what-is-the-best-practice-to-replace-class-name-using-jquery#comment52386393_32252850) has mentioned in my comments you could update the image by changing your CSS (assuming the sprite is only used in this instance):

**HTML**

```
<a id="course-progress-report-btn" href="#" class="disabled">
    <div class="sprites report_icon"></div>
    <span>COURSE PROGRESS REPORT</span>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
courseProgressBtn.attr('href', '#')
                 .addClass('disabled')
```

**CSS**

```
.course-progress-report-btn .sprites.report_icon
{
   //blue icon
}
.course-progress-report-btn.disabled .sprites.report_icon
{
   //gray icon
}
```

Comment: he could also use `toggleClass`

Comment: I prefer to be more specific than use `toggleClass`. What if some other logic somewhere else was already changing it to `report_icon_gray` for example..

Comment: @DenysSéguret Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @Curt, wouldnt `.toggleClass('report_icon_blue,report_icon_grey')` be equivalent to `.removeClass('report_icon_blue').addClass('report_icon_grey')`?

Comment: @AmmarCSE No, the latter is removing a specific class and adding a specific class. `toggleClass` assumes that the `report_icon_blue` is currently a class on the element.

Comment: @Curt, right, I meant for that specific case, it would be equivalent. Anyways, its no big deal.

Comment: @Curt Why is it a bad idea to test a class in JS to set a class in an inner element rather than having a simple CSS rule ? Are you seriously asking ?

Comment: @AmmarCSE Yeah for that specific case it would be the equivalent, and if the user was already using `toggleClass` I would've used that in my code example. But theres no point introducing bad practice into their existing code, just provide a solution to the bug.

Comment: @DenysSéguret You mean they should be using `.course-progress-report-btn .report_icon` and `.course-progress-report-btn.disabled .report_icon` in their CSS? This suggests the sprite is only used for this one purpose. It might be a sprite library which is used in other circumstances, so it shouldn't be localised to this instance.

Comment: @DenysSéguret In case the sprites are custom and only for this instance I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

With pure jQuery when you are sure the selected elements have class A and do not have class B, the simplest way is:

```
selection.toggleClass('A B')
```

Other possibility is to toggle all possible classes based on variable.

```
var cls ='B'
selection.toggleClass('A', cls=='A')
selection.toggleClass('B', cls=='B')
```

With jQueryUI the best practice is to use `switchClass` for this purpose.

http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/